# Cordova and Xcode compatibility on old Apple Hardware

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova, compatibility

I'm currently developing a mobile app using Cordova on Windows and Android, and I'd like to test it on Apple devices. I purchased a refurbished 2011 MacBook and an iPhone 6s cheaply in order to do this, but I'm running into frustrating compatibility issues regarding XCode. The MacBook can support OS X up to El Capitan, which can support XCode 9.1, but the iPhone, which has automatically upgraded to iOS 13.3, needs a newer version of XCode to compile to it, it seems. I can't find a way to downgrade the phone to an older version of iOS (apparently the current version cannot be jailbreak-ed) and as a result I can't write apps to the phone.

Anyone have any suggestions? I'm aware of device-emulation services like Browser Stack, but I'd like to find a solution that uses the technology I've already bought before I pay for a new service.

Comment: Sorry to tell you but if you want to develop for Apple, you need to use supported/up to date devices. The 2011 MacBook is really not the way to go. You should look into a MacMini (2014+)

Comment: Geez, what a freaking disgrace. I guess I should have researched it more, but I never imagined Apple has such poor support for it's older tech.

Comment: Also the older MacMini is still supported but probably not for long... iPhone6S is probably on its last year.